# Account preferences ListPreference does not show dialog, crashes/reboots device

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to store a some preferences with my custom accounts. I've defined

```
android:accountPreferences="@xml/account_preferences"
```

in my authenticator.xml, and res/xml/account_preferences.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Advanced settings">
    <ListPreference
        android:title="Marketplace"
        android:summary="Select marketplace"
        android:key="marketplaceId"
        android:defaultValue="715713"
        android:entries="@array/marketplaces"
        android:entryValues="@array/marketplaceIds"
        android:persistent="true"
    />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Both arrays are defined in res/values/arrays.xml in string-array elements.

When I go to Accounts & Sync and select an account I can see the Marketplace field there, however if i select it, my device (or emulator) freezes and reboots, with no error message written to LogCat.

Any ideas for how I can get past this? Do I need to specify an intent in the preferences file?

Also, side question, if I get this to work, how do I access the preferences for one particular account programmatically?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't recall.. :/

Comment: It is known Android bug. See similar topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838063/account-preferences-crashes-on-listpreference