# Launch Intent from account-authenticator accountPreferences screen?

Tags: settings, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, accountmanager

I have included the AccountManager code in my app to enable the user to create and manage their account from inside their Settings application.

I linked in the "accountPreferences" preferences file inside my account-authenticator definition, and the options show properly in the Settings > Accounts > My App screen. When I tap on one of them, instead of getting the activity I linked in, I get:

```
01-14 14:47:27.304: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:944)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:931)
    at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:967)
    at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:215)
```

I have the intents inside my PreferenceScreen defined as:

```
<intent
    android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:targetPackage="com.myapp.android"
    android:targetClass="com.myapp.android.activities.AccountForwardingActivity"/>
```

And the target activity is also defined as you'd expect, with no special flags other than an intent-filter to match that action (I have other custom actions listed as well).

```
<activity android:name=".activities.AccountForwardingActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myapp.android.PAYMENT_TYPES"/>
        <action android:name="com.myapp.android.ADDRESS_LIST"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I mark this intent, launched from Settings.apk, to be a new task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was putting the Preference Screens inside my PreferenceCategory.

This works fine:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="General Settings" />
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Account Settings"
    android:summary="Favorites, Orders, and more.">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.myapp.android"
        android:targetClass="com.myapp.android.activities.AccountForwardingActivity"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Nesting that PreferenceScreen inside the PreferenceCategory does not work, and results in the error above.